# Is it possible to have a single webapp which uses Azure B2C with different Configurations

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to have a single webapp which uses Azure B2C with following Configuration?

1. TenantA : Configured to use Azure B2C User Flow A : Facebook
   Identity Provider
2. TenantB : Configured to use Azure B2C User Flow B
   : Google Identity Provider
3. TenantC: Configured to use Azure B2C User
   Flow C : Microsoft Identity Provider

Comment: Setup multi-tenant Azure AD, here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom)

Comment: Check this out and see if it helps https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2017/07/27/developing-an-azure-ad-b2c-multi-tenant-application/ and here is the code repo for the same https://github.com/mrochon/b2cmultitenantapp

Comment: Any update for this issue?